# node.js proxied request body

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

I am having a simple problem getting the **response** body of a double proxied request using `node.js` and `node-http-proxy`.

What I am basically trying to do, is to set the IP and port of my server in Chrome as a proxy (which works), which will then proxy the request to an other server.

Here is how I do it :

```
var ip = {'xx.xx.xx.xx', 8080};

var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy({ 
    target: {
        port : ip[0], host : ip[1]
    }
});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);
    proxy.on('data', function() { console.log(data);});
}).listen(8001)
```

Unfortunately, none of the "on data" events are working for me here... The "end" events are, but I never managed to get the bodies. Does anyone know how to achieve this ? I need to save the body of each requests to a specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... this is off the top of my head. Note, that I'm proxying to port 80 since most websites serve on port 80. Change the code for your specific use case. This is in CoffeeScript.

**Log Request Headers:**

```
fs = require('fs')
httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

fsw = fs.createWriteStream('myfile.txt', flags: 'a', mode: 0666, encoding: 'utf8')
server = httpProxy.createServer  (req, res, proxy) ->
           req.connection.pipe(fsw) #runs in parallel with the proxy... don't you love Node.js?
           proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
             host: require('url').parse(req.url).hostname,
             port: 80
           })
server.listen(8080)
```

[JS Translation](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afs%20%3D%20require%28%27fs%27%29%0AhttpProxy%20%3D%20require%28%27http-proxy%27%29%0A%0Afsw%20%3D%20fs.createWriteStream%28%27myfile.txt%27%2C%20flags%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20mode%3A%200666%2C%20encoding%3A%20%27utf8%27%29%0Aserver%20%3D%20httpProxy.createServer%20%20%28req%2C%20res%2C%20proxy%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20req.connection.pipe%28fsw%29%20%23runs%20in%20parallel%20with%20the%20proxy...%20don%27t%20you%20love%20Node.js%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20proxy.proxyRequest%28req%2C%20res%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20host%3A%20require%28%27url%27%29.parse%28req.url%29.hostname%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20port%3A%2080%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0Aserver.listen%288080%29)

Put 'localhost' and port 8080 for your browser proxy. Does this work for you?

**Log Request Body:**

```
fs = require('fs')
httpProxy = require('http-proxy')


server = httpProxy.createServer  (req, res, proxy) ->
           body = ''
           req.on 'data', (chunk) ->
             body += chunk

           req.on 'end', ->
             fs.writeFile('mybody.txt', body, 'utf8')

           proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
             host: require('url').parse(req.url).hostname,
             port: 80
           })
server.listen(8080)
```

I tested this and can confirm that it logs the body of a POST/PUT.

**Log Response Body:**

```
fsw = fs.createWriteStream('myfile.txt', flags: 'a', mode: 0666, encoding: 'utf8')
server = httpProxy.createServer  (req, res, proxy) ->
  oldwrite = res.write
  res.write = (data, encoding, fd) ->
    fsw.write(data)
    res.write = oldwrite
    res.write(data, encoding, fd)
    res.write = oldwrite #<--- patch again before we leave the method


  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: require('url').parse(req.url).hostname,
    port: 80
  })

server.listen(8080)
```

Might not be the cleanest way, but I can confirm that it works.

Comment: Yea I just noticed that you're proxying to the site directly. I need a secondary proxy in the `proxy.ProxyRequest();`. So I modified it and yeah, nothing in the file, it's created but empty.

Comment: Still not piping anything ! :(

Comment: Yup, I did, but still the same result.

Comment: Create an 'append' write stream. I just tested this. I can verify it works.

Comment: Same result with append mode.

Comment: Actually it's working now but it's giving me headers, not the body !

Comment: Made an update again, I can confirm it works. Be careful though, this doesn't append to the file, you may want to change that if multiple POST/PUTS occur or have specific files for each request.

Comment: Try using this proxy for your request to test your code : 82.99.254.166:3128 (instead of your current host and port variables in your code) on a page like stackoverflow.com. I have empty "body" variables, hence empty files every time. But I am using GET requests, how do you use POST/PUTS ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain my problem properly. I am trying to save the **response** body of the proxied request !

Comment: What? A body with a GET request? The code verbatim above works. Go to lamernews.com and connect through the code above. Create an account. Behold your username and password in the text file. GET requests don't have a body at least they shouldn't and servers shouldn't expect them to.

Comment: It should be as simple as changing `req` to `res`. Does that work?

Comment: It's writing stuff to files most of the time, but I think there is an encoding problem with the binary data. Strangely not all the data is being sent to the files...

Comment: I get between 300 and 1500 bytes and then it stops. Very strange behavior... And it seems res.write is called only once per request.

Comment: Ah yes, that all makes sense. The 1500 comes from the capping of your MTU. The reason you don't get anymore is because their is a bug in the code. I updated. Essentially, what was happening, after the write, the patched value of res.write was being restored for that specific URL. Now, it's getting patched again. Does this work?

Comment: Please use one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for extended discussion.