# how to inspect requests response proxied through node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use node.js to setup a simple proxy server. The idea behind that is to get all web services calls made to one web service go through a node.js proxy in order to easily inspect and debug web service calls.

In order to do that, I am trying to use the following code to proxy the requests:

```
var
    url = require('url'),
    http = require('http'),
    acceptor = http.createServer().listen(8008);

acceptor.on('request', function(request, response) {
    console.log('request ' + request.url);
    request.pause();
    var options = url.parse(request.url);
    options.headers = request.headers;
    options.method = request.method;
    options.agent = false;

    var connector = http.request(options, function(serverResponse) {
            serverResponse.pause();
            response.writeHeader(serverResponse.statusCode, serverResponse.headers);
            serverResponse.pipe(response);
            serverResponse.resume();
    });
    request.pipe(connector);
    request.resume();
});
```

But I can't figure out where to inspect / dump to file the response. With node-inspector, I was looking at the response object at line: serverResponse.pipe(response); but the body of the response is not yet available.

I found the following question [node.js proxied request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351219/node-js-proxied-request-body) but it is written in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is write your own `'data'` handler and don't use `pipe()`.
You cannot eavesdrop on the data once you piped the stream.